# Can I install MacTex 2015 on an OS X Homebrew system without permission issues?

Tags: texlive, mactex, mac

I currently have a working MacTex 2014 installation and Homebrew installation on OS 10.10.3, and am about to install MacTex 2015. But I'm concerned about permission issues. Both packages install in `/usr/local`, and Homebrew requires very specific permissions on that directory to function.

Will installing MacTex 2015 change anything in my Homebrew installation? Will it in any way affect how Homebrew works?

Comment: I can't say this with absolute certainty but I would not expect problems and in fact, I didn't have any with the same configuration. The reason is that MacTeX will install into `/usr/local/texlive`, which already exists. The 2015 installation will live in its own subdirectory under `/usr/local/texlive`.

Comment: As Homebrew requires more permissive permissions than TeX Live, there really should be no issues. As noted by @ChristianLindig, I've got a similar but not identical set up and have had no problems.